# ngResource makes a request but does not parse results

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, ngresource

I am working on a webapp that uses ngResource to fetch backend data.  Here is my factory

```
App.factory('MyCoolResource', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  'use strict';
  return $resource('/rest/MyCoolResource');
}]);
```

Then in a Controller

```
console.log("Query: " + MyCoolResource.query())
```

In Chrome network inspector I can see the data coming back (an array of String)

```
["Foo","Bar","Gaz","Waka"]
```

But the console logging shows nothing:

```
Query:
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **console.log()** is getting called before the data arrives, because **MyCoolResource.query()** is asynchrone, try to use a callback that will be executed once the query ended and the data returned from the API then show this data via the **console.log()**:

```
MyCoolResource.query(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```