# Cannot bind ngResource to ngOptions

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, ngresource

I have a select element, and I want it populated with the result of a call to a resource via ngResource.

```
 <select chosen="" 
         required 
         data-ng-model="coolStuffSelected" 
         data-ng-options="stuff for stuff in coolStuff" 
         class="chosen-select input-md"></select>
```

In my Controller I have

```
CoolStuffResource.query(function(result){
  $scope.coolStuff = result;
  console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.coolStuff));
  // prints ["foo","bar","gaz","waka"]
});
```

I see the result logged, but the select is empty.  What am I doing wrong?

Update:  I tried this albeit hacky workaround, which is to access the ng-model :

```
MyCoolService.query(function(result){
  $scope.coolStuff = result;
  $scope.coolStuffSelected = null;
});
```

This works in Chrome, but does not work in Safari.  Simply hardcoding the values works fine in both browsers:

```
$scope.coolStuff = ["foo", "bar", "gaz", "waka"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0q3yjns/1/) from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932589/ngresource-makes-a-request-but-does-not-parse-results), demonstrating the returned data from there.

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="d for d in data"></select>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    MyCoolResource.query(function(result){
       $scope.data = result;
    });
}
```

Comment: But this is not working in the async case.  I know how to set the data manually, the issue only occurs when I call query, not when hard coding the data.  How do I fix this?

Comment: have you tried this solution with asynchronous requests such as from ngResource?   It does not work.

Comment: You can just use the $scope.data inside the **MyCoolstuffResource.query()** callback, i've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok I tried this, I think there might be an issue with the chosen library, I have opened this ticket there https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen/issues/106 .  Thank you for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

What does the JSON look like in your response?  Your ng-options expression is most likely wrong.  You need to tell it what you want displayed in your select.

Change your ng-options: so it looks something like this:

```
ng-options="stuff as stuff.label for coolstuff"
```

Change stuff.label to whatever property you want displayed in your select.

Take a look at this documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: This issue only occurs when using ngResource to query for the select options.  If I hardcode the data as suggested in the other answer it works fine.  Right now its just an array of string, soon I will need to derive a property as you illustrated.

Comment: Can you show the response you are getting back from the resource call? I think that is probably what I need to see to help anymore.

Comment: Sure thing, its just an array of string `["Foo", "Bar", "Gaz", "Waka-Waka"]`

Comment: That's what shows up when you log the response? It's not wrapped in an outside array?

Comment: What do you mean not wrapped in an outside array?  Yep, thats exactly what it looks like, it just appears to not be bound to the select with ng-options.

Comment: It looks like you are using the chosen directive. I just noticed that.  Which one are you using?  Usually, you need to pass your options into that directive by adding a options attribute like this: options="coolStuff" in addition to your ng-options attribute.

Comment: In general, make sure you have everything the chosen directive you are using requires.  It doesn't look like you are setting all the required attributes.  Also, ngResource/$http automatically runs the digest so you don't have to update anything manually.  I think this is an issue with how the chosen directive is being used.

Comment: Something is wrong with chosen or the way I am using it, I have opened this bug https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen/issues/106